# How to get data from the DB?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

There is an already created database. And I want to get data from there.
When I execute a query just for the test it always gives an empty value:

```
{
    "users": []
}
```

Why is this happening?

entity:

```
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column} from "typeorm";

@Entity()

export class User {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid") user_id: number;

    @Column("varchar2", { length: 100 }) login: string;

    @Column("varchar2", { length: 100 }) email: string;

    @Column("varchar2", { length: 50 }) phone: string;

    @Column() roles_id: number;

    @Column("varchar2", { length: 500 }) password: string;
}
```

controller:

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { User } from "../entity/User";
import { getRepository } from "typeorm";

class UserController {

    public async getUsers(req: Request, res: Response) {
        let users = await getRepository(User).find();
        await res.status(200).json({ users: users })
    } 
}

const userController = new UserController();

export default userController;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your entity refers to the correct table. You haven't explicitly provided a `name` in your entity declaration, so the default will be `user` (the singular form, not `user(s)` plural).

If your table is actually called `users`, you need to provide that in the `@Entity` decorator:

```
@Entity({ name: 'users' })
export class User { ... }
```

Comment: Is there any way to make that the default behavior? I feel like that's a standard pattern. Singular in the model, but plural in the db for table.